# Linux Script to check a process is up or not

Tags: linux, shell, email, smtp

I have a server Application which holds 1500 process id, I need a  shell Script which checks for every hour whether the process is up, if not start the process using "dsmc -u xxxx -p ****" if it is not started send a mail to my gmail(xxx@gmail.com). here is the code how can i send a mail to my gmail account.

```
   if pidof -s vsftpd = /dev/null; then
      echo 'ftp is stopped'

       sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
  else 
       echo "The FTP server is Down" | mail -s "Ftp Server is Down" abcd@example.com
   fi
```

I don't get mail to my Gmail Account. 
Reference: http://rtcamp.com/wordpress-nginx/tutorials/linux/ubuntu-postfix-gmail-smtp/

Answer (score 0):

to write your script you probably would want to investigate the following functions and their associated man pages

ps
pgrep
ptree
mail

Answer (score 0):

The script part is easy to do. Troubleshooting the mail however is not. I would recommend running the script in screen (screen -d -m /bin/bash "test.sh"), detaching the screen (ctrl -a + d) then killing the process (/etc/init.d/vsftp stop), waiting 1 minute, and reattach the screen (screen -r). That will provide you the error with mail you can troubleshoot.

The following script will monitor your service for you.

```
    #!/bin/bash

process="vsftp"

while true ; do

  until [ ! $(pgrep $process) ]; do
        sleep 1 #The number or minutes to wait until next check
  done

  #If process is not found do the following
  /etc/init.d/$process start > /dev/null #Run as root because sudo requires password
  if [ $? != 1 ]; then
  echo "The FTP server was restarted" | mail -s "Ftp Server $process was restarted" abcd@example.com
  else
  echo "The FTP server could not restart" | mail -s "Ftp Server $process is down" abcd@example.com
  sleep 1
  exit 0;
  fi

done
```

Hope this helps and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

We can do the script with ps -ef

try,

```
 # cat vsftpd.sh
 #!/bin/bash
 /bin/ps -ef | grep vsftpd > /dev/null 2>&1
 if [ $? -ne 0 ]
 then
 /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart > /dev/null 2>&1
 /bin/mail -s "FTP service is RESTARTED now" abcd@example.com
 else
 sleep 0
 fi
```

cron:

```
 * * * * * /bin/sh /path/to/vsftpd.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```